# Tkinter's 'create_text' inconsistent between raspberry pis

Tags: pi-3, python-3, raspberry-pi-os, tkinter, pi-models

This one has me completely stumped, hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

Here's my MRE of the issue:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = 200
h = 200

c = Canvas(root, width=w, height=h, bg='lightgrey')

txt = c.create_text(w/2, h/2, font=("Helvetica", 20, "bold"), text="Dummy Text", anchor="center")
c.create_line(0, h/2, w, h/2, fill="green", width=2)
c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This code creates a simple 200x200 canvas with a green line across the center. It also draws some text in the center of the window. The strange thing is, the outcome is slightly different on one of my Raspberry Pis.

Here is the result on my Mac:

[image: Mac Result]

The Result on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, which matches the result on my Mac:

[image: Model B Result]

And finally, the strange outcome on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model A+:
[image: Model A+ Result]

As you can hopefully tell from the images, the text on the A+ is drawing slightly higher than on the other two systems. The text on the A+ is farther above the green centerline than on my mac and RPi B, which draw the text mostly below the green centerline.

Some Relevant Details:

- All systems are running the same code
- All systems are using Python 3.9.5
- All systems are using tkinter version 8.6
- Mac OSX: Big Sur 11.3
- RPi B OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- RPi A+ OS: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

The text appears to be drawing in the same pixel location on all systems when using print statements to expose the x y locations.

Any idea what could be causing this difference in its visual drawing location? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was able to resolve this by downgrading the A+ OS to Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). If anyone has any insight as to why Bullseye may make a difference for a tkinter method, I would love to fix this as opposed to patch it.

Comment: aspect ratios of lettering look different.  instead of camera pics, could you use a screenshot from each device?  would help tell if it is font related.